# How does one rename multiple files using python?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, append, rename

I have lots of programming experience but this is my first python script. I am trying to add the prefix "00" to all the files in a specific folder. First I read the names of all the files and save them in an array. Then I sort through the array and add the prefix "00" then use the os.rename function but somewhere along the way I've messed up something.

```
import sys, os

file_list = []

for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    file_list.append(file)

 for i in file_list:
    file_list[i] = prevName
    newName = '00' + file_list[i]
    os.rename(prevName, newName)
```

I have a .py file in the folder with all the files I want to rename. The .py file contains the script above. When i double click the .py file a cmd window flashes and disappears and none of the file names have been changed. Any help would be appreciated, sorry if this is a very obvious mistake, my python level is quite n00b at the moment.

Comment: First of all, run python from console, rather than double-clicking it, so that you can see what exception is it throwing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @Padraic, also make following changes to your code.

```
import sys, os

file_list = []

for f in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    file_list.append(f)

for i in range(len(file_list)):
    prevName = file_list[i]
    if prevName != 'stackoverflow.py':  # Mention .py file so that it doesnt get renamed
        newName = '00' + file_list[i]
        os.rename(prevName, newName)
```

Comment: thank you both very much, using both of your suggestions the script ran perfectly

Comment: @ErrorMaster, you don't need to create any lists, you need os.listdir and nothing else, you also need to join the path to the file if you plan on passing in a directory name

Answer (score 1):

Your code errors because you provide no args so `sys.argv[1]` would give an IndexError, you would need to call the script with the dir name from a cmd prompt not double click it:

```
python your_script directory <- argv[1]
```

Or change the code and specify the path, you also need to join the path to the filename.

```
path = "full_path"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    curr,new = os.path.join(path,f), os.path.join(path,"00{}".format(f))
    os.rename(curr,new)
```

`os.listdir` returns a list so just iterate over that, you don't need to create a list and append to it.

`for i in file_list:` would also make each `i` a filename not an index so that would cause another error but as above you don't need to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your indentation. The second `for` loop is not indented correctly.
2. `for i in file_list:
       file_list[i] = prevName`

   You are not iterating correctly. `for` loops in Python are like `foreach` loops you may know from other programming languages. `i` in `for i in file_list` actually gives you the list's elements, so you should be doing
   `for i in range(len(file_list)):
       file_list[i] = ......`

   although it is not very pythonic nor generally a good idea to modify the collection that you're currently iterating over.